# detect which uiview is touched

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have custom view that should be clicked and do some action.
I have two CustomView in same screen. I want to detect which one is clicked to do different action.

Is it possible to set some ids there to detect which one is clicked exactly?

Here is my CustomView

```
protocol CostomViewDelegate: class {
    func viewClicked()
}

class CostomView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizer {

    @IBOutlet  weak var placeholderlbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet  weak var textLbl: UILabel!
    weak var delegate: CostomViewDelegate?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        delegate?.viewClicked()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use delegation, then you should change your delegate function so that the view provides a reference to itself to the delegate.

```
protocol CostomViewDelegate: class {
    func costomView(clicked: CostomView)
}

class CostomView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizer {

    @IBOutlet  weak var placeholderlbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet  weak var textLbl: UILabel!
    weak var delegate: CostomViewDelegate?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        delegate?.costomView(clicked: self)
    }

}
```

Then in your delegate function you can compare the value of the passed reference or other properties in order to take the appropriate action:

```
func costomView(clicked: CostomView) {
    if clicked == self.costomView1 {
      // Do something
    } else if clicked == self.costomView2 {
      // Do something else
    }
}
```

You could also add a property to your `CostomView` class that holds a closure and invoke that closure when the view is tapped.  This is, perhaps, a more "modern" approach, but delegation is still valid and how you do it is a matter of opinion.  Personally, one advantage I see for delegation is when viewingthe code you can quickly locate the delegate function in a class, while a closure may be less obvious.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer it really helped me. I thought the 'modern' way is use delegation could you just send me an example link of 'holds closure and invoke closure'? I truly didn't get it what is that mean.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it - define touch behaviour for your `CostomView`, from parent class or view controller for example with closures. The fastest **(but pretty ugly)** way - set different tags for these views and code different behaviour for different tags.